# Conversion of python file to exe rise error

Tags: python, py2exe, setup.py

I am new and Python and programming. I tried to write code which needs one .docx, one .xlsx and one image file to work correctly. When I tried to convert it to .exe format with py2exe, something went wrong and setup broke! My setup.py file is as follows:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

includes = ["tkinter", "sys", "lxml._elementpath"]
packages = ["tkinter", "docx", "pandas"]

if __name__ == '__main__': #Use dunder method as a best practice

    Mydata_files = []
    for files in os.listdir("C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/"):
        f1 = "C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/" + files
        if os.path.isfile(f1):
            f2 = 'images', [f1]
            Mydata_files.append(f2)

    setup(console = ['Combobox.py'],
          data_files = Mydata_files,
          options={"py2exe":{"compressed": 0,
                             "includes": includes,
                             "packages": packages,
                             "unbuffered": True,
                             "optimize": 2,
                             "bundle_files": 1,
                             "dist_dir": ".",
                             "xref": False,
                             "skip_archive": False,
                             "ascii": False}})
```

And my error message is as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf34.py", line 675, in __code__
    raise RuntimeError("compiling %r" % self) from None
RuntimeError: compiling Module(_pydev_imps._pydev_pkgutil_old, 'C:\\Users\\Murat\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\debugpy\\_vendored\\pydevd\\_pydev_imps\\_pydev_pkgutil_old.py')
```

Comment: Python is for .exe as water is for oil.

Comment: May be but I have to solve this problem.